# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.quartz.jobs.FileScanListener

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling, quartz

Recenlty upgarded the quartz scheduler jar from version 2.1.6 to 2.3.2 . Having the quartz.properties set to old configuration having called the plugin XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin in my quartz.properties i have started receiving classNotFound exception. So i went ahead and decompiled the quartz jar and found that the org.quartz.jobs package itself is missing from 2.3.2 version. Can anyone help with overcoming this issue??

The exception is receive is below:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.quartz.jobs.FileScanListener
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:607) ~[?:1.8.0-internal]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:844) ~[?:1.8.0-internal]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:823) ~[?:1.8.0-internal]
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:325) ~[?:1.8.0-internal]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:803) ~[?:1.8.0-internal]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0-internal]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:349) ~[?:1.8.0-internal]
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:154) ~[?:1.8.0-internal]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:727) ~[?:1.8.0-internal]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$400(URLClassLoader.java:95) ~[?:1.8.0-internal]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$ClassFinder.run(URLClassLoader.java:1182) ~[?:1.8.0-internal]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:686) ~[?:1.8.0-internal]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:602) ~[?:1.8.0-internal]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:844) ~[?:1.8.0-internal]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:823) ~[?:1.8.0-internal]
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:325) ~[?:1.8.0-internal]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:803) ~[?:1.8.0-internal]
        at org.quartz.simpl.InitThreadContextClassLoadHelper.loadClass(InitThreadContextClassLoadHelper.java:72) ~[quartz-2.3.2.jar:?]
        at org.quartz.simpl.CascadingClassLoadHelper.loadClass(CascadingClassLoadHelper.java:114) ~[quartz-2.3.2.jar:?]
        at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.instantiate(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1084) ~[quartz-2.3.2.jar:?]
        ... 3 more
```

Below is my quartz.properties :

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = TESTAPP
org.quartz.scheduler.jmx.export = true
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 5

org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore

org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.class = org.quartz.plugins.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.fileNames = testapp-jobs.xml
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.failOnFileNotFound = true
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.scanInterval = 0
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.wrapInUserTransaction = false
```

Comment: Use this [quartz jar](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/quartz-scheduler/quartz-jobs/2.3.2/) file available in this repository, as i could see the FileScanListener class file with package name as org.quartz.jobs. If this solution works let me know.

Comment: Thanks worked for the issue i was facing, didn't realise that the dependecy of quratz-jobs was provide as an individual package. Thanks for the help -josepraveen

Comment: I have added my solution as an answer. please mark my answer as accepted. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From this maven [repository](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/quartz-scheduler/), you need to use `quartz-jobs` jar file with latest version.

I could see the FileScanListener.class file under the package named as `org.quartz.jobs`.

[image: solution]

I hope this helps.